# Problems with addEventListener('deviceready') in cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, addeventlistener

I'm trying to use "Cordova Local-Notification Plugin" in my cordova application without success. For example, the following doesn't work:

> `console.log(now);`

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5 * 1000);
    console.log(now);
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        text:"Delayed Notification",
        at:_5_sec_from_now,
        led:"FF0000",
        sound:null
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Cordova `deviceready` not firing

Check you are including `cordova.js` or `phonegap.js` in your index.html

If Cordova is not loaded, the event will not be fired.

Also check for any console errors in Xcode.

### Using Web Inspector to Debug Mobile Safari

You can use Safari to inspect Cordova apps running on real devices.

More info here:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

[image]

When working in the browser, `deviceready` does not fire, it only fires on a real device. This also means you can't test the plugins easily in the browser.

To get around this, you can detect if cordova is loaded and call and setup function yourself.

```
function setup() {
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _5_sec_from_now = new Date(now + 5 * 1000);
    console.log(now);

    // ** this will not work in browser **
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        text:"Delayed Notification",
        at:_5_sec_from_now,
        led:"FF0000",
        sound:null
    });
}


// check if codova is loaded
if (!!window.cordova){
    // running on device
    // wait for plugins to load
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', setup, false);    
}else{
    // running in browser
    // call setup anyway
    setTimeout(setup, 200);
}
```

Comment: cordova.js is already including. I'm writing this code to index.js file and to another pages, but it's don't work anything.

Comment: make sure `cordova.js` is in the `head` and near the top. in the `Log` in Xcode, does it mention any errors?

Comment: cordova.js adding in the first place in head. And I'm work in Windows with nodejs. I make tests in browser and genymotion, and have not any errors in log.

Comment: ah :D.... i know this issue...
`deviceready` doesn't fire in the browser, only fires on device.
I have some code to work around this...
1 second, i'll find it.

Comment: Thank you so much!